# Cant connect to remote machine 'ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer'

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssh, tomcat7

I have right to remote server, For some reason I have to give access to my tomcat user. But by mistake I had changed user and group to tomcat7 user by below command:

```
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /
```

Then I am not able to login my virtual box using ssh and filezilla.
getting below error:

> ssh root@hostname ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
>   by peer

Answer (score 2):

Ouch, if that chown cmd succeeded you must have been executing it as root and if so - I'm afraid you changed the owner and group for the entire filesystem - I don't think you can recover your system entirely anymore.

You *might* be able to (but don't keep your hopes up):

- ssh tomcat@hostname
- su -

This would give you a chance to salvage some stuff.

Don't reboot the system - it'll likely not come back up again.

Comment: I already tried this, but didnt help me. ssh tomcat@hostname is not working.

Then I restarted my virtual box but it is also not working. Killed the process by digital ocean console. Then I am able to login using ssh but the whole system has user and group tomcat7. It is hard time for me to get it work as normal. As mysql, tomcat and other such program needs rights for specific users.

So I am afraid that I will never get my box as it was before.

Comment: Build a new box. Use the successfull ssh login to extract configs and data from the old system and port them to the new one. Careful with copying to not overwrite file ownership in the new system!

Comment: Alternatively (but with a LOT of work) you can use the new system as reference to restore the proper user:group ownership of files in the old one.